# when interface method override always use access modifier public why?

Tags: java, android

```
 1. 

interface A { 
 void display(); 
 } 
class B implements A { 
//not use here private,protected,default...... 
**public** void display(){
  System.out.println("i m interface method"); 
} 
public static void main(String args[]){
 A a1 = new B(); 
a1.display();
 }

}
```

---

i am totally confusion please help me....and sorry for my English. Thank u

Comment: It would be great if you [format your code first](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44386442/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you must use `public` in your class, is because your method is *implicitly* `public` from the interface. The Java tutorial [Defining an Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html) says, in part,

> All abstract, default, and static methods in an interface are implicitly `public`, so you can omit the `public` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Interface states that your class should have some methods, you are not allowed to hide them (by making private), if you want to implement interface.

Method is public in Interface by a default, you are now allowed to reduce it visibility area=)